# подскажите написание "не"

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать: **незагерметизированный ящик передать на склад** или **не загерметизированный ящик передать на склад**?

Answer (score 2):

Слитно пишется, отрицания же нет.